# Filter a Scala Seq[(String, String)] using a Seq[String]

Tags: scala, type-conversion, sequence

I have this `Seq[(String, String)]` :

```
val tupleSeq: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(
  ("aaa", "A_A_A"),
  ("bbb", "B_B_B"),
  ("ccc", "C_C_C")
)
```

I want to use the given `seqA` on `tupleSeq`:

```
val seqA: Seq[String] = Seq("aaa", "bbb")
```

In order to obtain :

```
val seqB: Seq[String] = Seq("A_A_A", "B_B_B")
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scala
val tupleSeq: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(
  ("aaa", "A_A_A"),
  ("bbb", "B_B_B"),
  ("ccc", "C_C_C")
)

val seqA: Seq[String] = Seq("aaa", "bbb")

// List(A_A_A, B_B_B)
val seqB = for {
      key <- seqA
      value <- tupleSeq.find(_._1 == key).map(_._2)
    } yield value
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use the data unaltered.

```
// The size of `data` is M
// The size of `query` is N

val data: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(
  ("aaa", "A_A_A"),
  ("bbb", "B_B_B"),
  ("ccc", "C_C_C")
)

val query: Seq[String] = Seq("aaa", "bbb")

// Use the data as is
// O(M * N)

for {
  (key, value) <- data
  lookup <- query
  if key == lookup
} yield value
```

The problem with this approach is that the overall complexity is `O(M * N)`, where `M` and `N` are the sizes of the `data` and `query` collections. This might be completely acceptable if either `M` or `N` are known to be very small and can be further improved in practical terms by making use of functions that can terminate early (like `find`, exemplified in another answer).

If `M` and `N` are reasonably large, you might want to spend the time necessary to convert them into an appropriate data structure (which consumes time and space in a way which is linear to the size of the collection).

Depending on which size you expect to be larger you might want to either turn the data into a map and look up the relevant keys or turn the query into a set and iterate each key in the map to find which is relevant.

I would expect the data to be queried in most cases to be larger than the query, so probably you may want to turn the data into a map. Keeping the map around would also allow you to query it multiple times without suffering from the time to turn it into a more appropriate structure for querying.

```
// Turn the query into a set and iterate the data
// O(M)

val lookups = query.toSet
data.collect {
  case (key, value) if lookups.contains(key) => value
}

// Turn the data into a map and iterate the query
// O(N)

val map = data.toMap
query.collect(map)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/Bull5v9QSjapLU4cR540Fg/12).

Answer (score 2):

Your `tupleSeq` naturally looks like a `Map` of key-to-value pairs, so you should treat it like one. The code becomes very simple with this observation:

```
  val myMap = tupleSeq.toMap
  val seqB  = seqA.collect(myMap) // List(A_A_A, B_B_B)
```

For additional space complexity, you get O(1) amortized time complexity for your query, which is an acceptable trade-off and arguably a better solution than linear searches through the sequence.

**Note** the use of `collect` instead of `map` because it discards keys that do not have a mapping value in your `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

`val seqB = tupleSeq.filter{x => seqA.contains(x._1)}.map(x => x._2)`

It filters the sequence and keeps the tuples where the first value is part of your second sequence, and then maps the tuples to the second value.

`seqB.foreach(println)` then outputs this:

```
A_A_A
B_B_B
```